# Android : Create Service as Independent Project

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, project

I am working on an Android app that has two main projects:

- The main activity
- A service

These two projects are independent and I can't link them together.

I've tried Broadcast Receiver, Remote Service, Manifest permissions.. but it doesn't work. I know how to do it when they are in different packages and in the same project.

Has someone ever done something like this?

Comment: Why cant you use the service inside your main project?

Comment: Because it is going be used by several applications, not only this one.

Comment: are you mentioned the service in your manifest if that service is in different package then mention<service android:name="packagename.service"/> in your manifest i think this will helps you.

Comment: @codingdevil : if i only add this to the service manifest, where is the link between the service and the app ? I just need a way to start the service without using the BOOT_START

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must bind with your service with a Binder

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

and

[how do i start (and bind) a remote service in android that is implemented in another app (different package)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075165/how-do-i-start-and-bind-a-remote-service-in-android-that-is-implemented-in-ano)

Comment: With the answer given by CommonsWare, do I have to use Biding or can I use only the action string and go Intent("action string") ?

Comment: you must use both `Intent intent = new Intent("this.is.my.custom.ACTION"); bindService(intent, sConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`